# Is it possible to resize/move root and encrypted home partitions in Ubuntu 14.04 without losing data?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption, gparted

There seems to be quite a few pages on how to re-partition a hard-drive without lead to loss of data. There are also pages that state that it is not possible with encrypted drives, and other stating that it is only possible using the command line utilities. I am a bit sceptical as there does not seem to be any hands on instructions how this can be done. Some guidance and links to how this can be done would be helpful. I understand that without encryption one needs to boot from a live-CD or usb, and run Gparted. I have a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 Windows 7 laptop. The partitions are as follows: I want to increase sda10 (/) and move/decrease sda9 (/home).

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x75487944

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      409599      203776    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          409600   124969634    62280017+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       124971006  1465147119   670088057    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1435705408  1464936447    14615520    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6      1464936511  1465147119      105304+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda7       124971008   124973055        1024   83  Linux
/dev/sda8      1415692288  1415694335        1024   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       124975104   184971263    29998080   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      184973312  1403674623   609350656   83  Linux
/dev/sda11     1403676672  1415677951     6000640   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda12     1415696384  1435697151    10000384    b  W95 FAT32

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 6144 MB, 6144655360 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 747 cylinders, total 12001280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4079e40a

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is that ecryptfs is a filesystem encryption and only encrypts files not partitions, so it should be safe to resize the partition, but make a backup first! I'm flagging this as a duplicate, because [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166044/how-to-resize-an-ext4-encrypted-home-partition) has been asked before.